# Texture not on whole face

Tags: texturing

I am trying to create my first basic model and render post tutorials. I have created a model of a Coke can (other soft drinks are available) and added a quick texture I aquired off google images.

The problem is that for some reason the texture does not appear to cover the entire face. I think the issue is related to the subdivision modifier I am using as if I turn it off then the texture appears correctly.

Issue
[image: Issue]

Subdivision turned off
[image: Subdivision turned off]

I have done some googling but cant find anything, can anyone help?

Comment: In the Subdivision Surface modifier, there's an option called Subdivide UVs, doesn't it fix the problem?

Comment: @moonboots answer helped me find the solution, although I couldnt see a Subdivide UVs option. IU tried simple instead of Catmull-Clark subdivision and it worked.. I googled the difference and it came back that the final vertex will be an average of the current ones, so adding an edge loop neat the bottom edge fixed it!

Comment: in 2.8 the Subdivision Surface modifier's option becomes "Smooth, keep corners", I think it's what you're looking for. Don't add edge loops, don't use Simple instead of Catmull-Clark.

Answer (score 2):

@moonboots answer helped me find the solution, although I couldnt see a Subdivide UVs option. IU tried simple instead of Catmull-Clark subdivision and it worked.. I googled the difference and it came back that the final vertex will be an average of the current ones, so adding an edge loop neat the bottom edge fixed it!